# Install Openfoam7 through docker, but no bashrc file

Tags: docker, bashrc

I installed openfoam7 in my Mac through Docker, Now I am trying to run the Allrun, which is start with

```
#!/bin/bash cd ${0%/*} || exit 1
# Source OpenFOAM BASH profile . /opt/openfoam7/etc/bashrc
```

but it failed, it said cannot find bashrc file.

Here are what I have in opt/openfoam7/etc:

```
|-- caseDicts
|-- codeTemplates
|-- config.csh
|-- config.sh
|-- templates
`-- thermoData
```

How could I solve it?

Comment: You said you installed it on your Mac using Docker. Did you build the docker image yourself or is it out on docker hub? Can you provide a link to it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the file is missing in your image. However, you can download the file from the project's git repository [1], and then copy it into your image.

In your Dockerfile,

```
COPY bashrc /opt/openfoam7/etc/
```

Note: the path of the file is relative to the `Dockerfile`.

[1]: https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/OpenFOAM-plus/blob/master/etc/bashrc